# Use of kernrel and range.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Is there any use of the kernel and the range?
Any 'aplication' works for me, is it used to prove an important theorem?

Comment: This is a very hard question to answer, because it is similar to asking about when addition and multiplication are used. The answer to this is "almost any time you use morphisms, you need to talk about their kernel and range." The words kernel and range are used in a variety of areas of algebra, so it would help to clarify where you saw them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One key application is in least squares. The equation $$ Ax = b$$ may be overdetermined and have no solution. That means that $b$ is not in the range of $A$. Notice that the range is the column space, and so the pre-image of the range is the row space, which is the range of the transpose. But one also has that the pre-image of the range is the orthogonal complement of the kernel, so that means the orthogonal complement of the range is just the kernel of the tranpose.

This means that if one writes $b$ as $u + v$ where $u$ is in the range of $A$ and $v$ is in its orthogonal complement (which is the kernel of the transpose), one can get rid of the part $v$ by applying the transpose to both sides. In this way one gets the so-called "normal" equation, which gives $$A^TAx = A^Tb $$ That equation is guaranteed to have a solution (since the part in the orthogonal complement of the range is gone), and though it might have many solutions they are all as close as possible in the least squares sense to the range of $A$. Hence the solution to the normal equation gives the least-squares solution to the overdetermined problem.